# MapXtreme compatibility with with .NET CORE

Tags: mapxtreme

In my office we are looking to use MapXtreme 9.0 for a new project we have. Is there a way to have MapXtreme support using .NET Core?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Pitney Bowes has no plans to support .NET Core in MapXtreme. See the official "solution" [here](https://support.pitneybowes.com/VFP05_KnowledgeWithSidebarHowTo?id=kA11E000000TNoOSAW&popup=false&lang=en_US).